# Trig inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having trouble with this problem.

[image]

I want to start by diving by 2, so that the right side of the inequality is root3 / 2
From there, use the trig identity of:

sin(A - B) = sinAcosB - cosAsinB

to eventually get:

-sin(t) < root3/2

But I'm unsure if it should be:

-2sin(t) < root3

Comment: You should stop at $-\sin(t) \leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, move the negative sign to the other side and flip the inequality, and then use your extensive knowledge of the unit circle to tell what $t$ is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$-\sin(t) \lt \frac{\sqrt 3}2 \iff \sin(t) \gt -\sqrt 3/2$$

Can you find the interval on the unit circle for which $$\sin(t)> -\sqrt 3/2\;\;?$$

Hint: $$\sin(3\pi/2 \pm \pi/6) = -\sqrt 3/2$$

Comment: Thanks for your help, that makes sense. So would it be when 8pi/6 > t > 10pi/6 ?